# Splitting a float tuple to multiple columns in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used regex to extract patterns from a csv document, mainly the pattern is (qty x volume in L), eg: 2x2L or 3x4L. (Note that 1 cell can have more than 1 pattern, eg: I want 2x4L and 3x1L)

```
0                                 []
1               [(2, x1L), (2, x4L)]
2               [(1, x1L), (1, x4L)]
3                         [(2, x4L)]
4               [(1, x4L), (1, x1L)]
                   ...              
95                        [(1, x2L)]
96              [(1, x1L), (1, x4L)]
97                        [(2, x1L)]
98                        [(6, x1L)]
99    [(6, x1L), (4, x2L), (4, x4L)]
Name: cards__name, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

I want to create 3 columns called "1L" "2L" and "4L" and then for every item, take the quantity and add it to the relevant row under the relevant column.

As such

```
1L 2L 4L
2  0  2
1  0  1
0  0  4
1  0  1
```

However I am not able to index to index the tuple in order to extract the quantity and the volume size for every item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before you will be able to use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) you have to normalize your columns, e.g. this way:

```
df['multiplier_1'] = df['order_1'].apply(lambda r: r[0])
df['base_volume_1'] = df['order_1'].apply(lambda r: r[1])
```

In such a way you will be able to ungroup the orders and eventually split into multiple base volumes.

Comment: as with before i'm getting the same error

'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Provide the actual data. The one in the question does not seem to be the one you are using.

Comment: 0                                 []
1               [(2, x1L), (2, x4L)]
2               [(1, x1L), (1, x4L)]
3                         [(2, x4L)]
4               [(1, x4L), (1, x1L)]
                   ...              
95                        [(1, x2L)]
96              [(1, x1L), (1, x4L)]
97                        [(2, x1L)]
98                        [(6, x1L)]
99    [(6, x1L), (4, x2L), (4, x4L)]
Name: cards__name, Length: 100, dtype: object

This is the full data

Comment: How about updating the question with this information?

Comment: Is there a column name? And why it seems that there is only 1 column whereas before there were 3?

Comment: I split them into 3 columns, in the question i pasted the result of the regex pattern. (1 column) to show the initial data i had